# Environment variables not updating for ASP.net Core application running on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, environment-variables

I have an ASP.net Core application thats setup to use Environment Variables Configuration, I have published the app and created a Web Application thats running "below" the IIS Default Web Site.
The Web Application is running on its own App Pool and LoadUserProfile is set to true, and the identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity.
My problem is that as soon as I change one of my environment variables and recycle the app pool, the web application does not pick up the changed values of my environment variables (which it should).
To get the environment variables to get picked up by the application I need to run iisreset (just restarting the IIS from the GUI manager isnt enough)

However, I have the very same setup in a different server, with one exception, the Identity of the App Pool is set to a specific account, and in this scenario the application does indeed pickup any changes made to an environment variable after an app pool recycle.

Has anyone had the same issue? How did you resolve it?
It isnt ideal to be "forced" to run iisreset if your running multiple Web Sites and/or Web Applications in the same IIS.. so thats not really an option. But as mentioned it seems to have something to do with which identity is set for the app pool.. but I might be wrong.. anyone has any thoughts?

I have googled for a solution, however.. the only thing I did find was an issue on github thats closed by now where they solved it by running iisreset.. also alot of posts on the web mentioned to set LoadUserProfile to true for the application pool and also to recycle the pool, but as mentioned.. thats the thing that doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

please check the environment variables on IIS.

1. Open the IIS Manager and select your website
2. Open "Configuration Editor" from "Management" section
3. On the first dropdown (section), select
   "system.webServer/aspNetCore"
4. On the second (from), select web.config
5. Then select "environmentVariables",you can add/remove buttons to configure as you want.

[image]

Comment: Doesnt this only apply if you have set the env variables in your Web.config? And not if you use PowerShell or GUI or the set x=y command?

Comment: You can change it by Appcmd or PowerShell in the Generate Script, such as `appcmd.exe set config "aspcoreMVC" -section:system.webServer/aspNetCore /+"environmentVariables.[name='1',value='2']"` or `Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/aspcoreMVC'  -filter "system.webServer/aspNetCore/environmentVariables" -name "." -value @{name='1';value='2'}`.